# DiffEQ and equilibriums

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I would like someone to tell me if they think my DiffEQ is set up right, and how to get me in the right direction where I end up (with work shown below) on solving it for P(t).  Or letting me know that I don't need to solve it to get the equilibrium.

Question: The population of a species of elk on Reading Island in Canada has been monitored for some years.  When the population was 600 elk, the relative birth and death rates were 35% and 15%, respectively.  When the population grew to 800 elk, the corresponding figures were 30% and 20%.
A) Write a DE to model the population as a function of time.  Assume that relative growth rate is a linear function of population.
B) Find the equilibrium size of the population.  Today there are 900 elk on the island.  How do you expect the population to change in the future?
There are two more parts, but I think if I get these answered I can do the rest.

My work----------
Using the equation dP/dt = kP(1-P/L) where P(t) = 1/(1+A(e^(-kt))) and A = (L-Po)/Po

L = 2000 elk; A = 7/3; P(t) = L/(1+(L-600/600)e^(-kt))

dP/dt = k(2000/(1+7/3e^(-kt)))*(1-(2000/{1+[7/3e^(-kt)]})/2000)

```
                  Did I simplify this incorrectly to:
                          dP/dt = k * (P-2000)
                                   ?
```

If I did, could you please give me a suggestion?  I tried redoing that and got to a very much more complicated result, so I'm really hoping I did incorrect simplification, and I *did* simplify it correctly the first time above.

Thank you.

Comment: You'll need to use latex, the maths in your question is nigh on impossible to read.. See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @Mattos Is there a way to upload a picture?  I don't have time or patience to try to rewrite everything.  But thank you for responding!

Comment: You can upload pictures but I don't know how to. People on this site won't help you with your question if they can't read it, so you'll need to learn latex. Also, it's not that hard.. Just put $ symbols around the maths text and some simple commands include use \frac{}{} to make a fraction and for a power use ^{}..